# URLConnection with arabic parameters

Tags: arabic, urlconnection

i'm trying to develop an android application which contains arabic data , so i've got a problem ;

```
URL twitter = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/WS/identi_el.php?id1="+nomm+"&id2="+pren+"&id3="+pa);
```

these parameters (nomm , pren and pa ) are in arabic language so it doesn't return any result , however , when i put them in french it returns results so can anyone helps me how to make URLConnection supports arabic letters please ?

Answer (score 0):

Non alphanumeric characters except `-`, `_` and `.` are know to cause issues in URLs, I bet you'll run into the same problem if you use a french word with an accent.

So stay on the safe side and [encode](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) all parameters before using them as part query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the URL from

```
URL twitter = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/WS/identi_el.php?id1="+nomm+"&id2="+pren+"&id3="+pa);
```

to

`url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/WS/identi_el.phpid1="+java.net.URLEncoder.encode(nomm,"utf8")+"&id2="+java.net.URLEncoder.encode(pren,"utf8")+"&id3="+java.net.URLEncoder.encode(pa,"utf-8"));`

=> I just added the following java.net.URLEncoder.encode(...,"utf8") for each parameter and it's working :)